# Как сделать редирект папок в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

На сайте A.B.com css подгружается из A.B.com/css. Как с помощью htaccess сделать так, что бы css грузился из B.com/css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в [документации](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) есть [примеры](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs):

```
redirect permanent /css/ http://b.com/css/
```

Comment: почему то это работает только когда в браузере набираешь ссылку A.B.com/css, тогда редиректит на B.com/css. А если зайти на страницу A.B.com и нажать f12, то вижу, что страница пытается загружать файлы с A.B.com/css. plasmon.rghost.ru/8YDpJVLWc/image.png

Comment: браузер должен получать перенаправление при загрузке файлов, путь к которым начинается с `/css/`. судя же по вашему комментарию, вы хотите, чтобы в самом html-коде присутствовали другие адреса. а это делается не с помощью настроек http-сервера, а изменением самого html-кода.

Comment: Редирект, это то что нужно в данном случае. Нашел еще решение <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule [%,a-zA-Z0-9/-/+/()]+[.]{1}[css] http://B.com/%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>